# Date range and discrete dates schedules using quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I want to run jobs in 2 ways:

1. Between 2 date ranges excluding certain weekdays(ex: monday, wednesday, friday) : starttime and end time is given
2. On specific dates only (02-05-2012, 07-05-2012, 20-05-2012 etc..) : starttime and end time is given

How do i build 2 separate triggers for these two schedules ?

Answer (score 0):

For 1 you can use a single [org.quartz.CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html) with a startTime and endTime and your 'certain weekday' excluding cron expression.

For 2 you can use a [org.quartz.CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html) for each specific date, setting startTime and endTime as the start and end of that day and a cron expression for your repetition requirements.